# Can't Center Fixed Div

Tags: html, css, web

I have read through countless threads on here and others, but have yet to find one that works for me. I am trying to get this darn div to center on the bottom of my page. It is kind of like a footer, but not exactly.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.uah.edu"><img style="width:270px; height:150px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:15px;" src="style/images/UAH.png"></a></li>
            <li>another big test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#menucontainer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

#menu{
    position:fixed;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    bottom:0px;
    height:200px;
    width:1218px;
    border:3px solid #000000;
    box-shadow:0px -5px 5px #888888;
}

li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    height:190px;
    width:300px;
    border-left:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Please filter your code so we see *only* the relevant parts to your question.

Comment: Which div are you trying to centre?

Comment: I think OP wants to centre the #menucontainer by the look o the css, the code given could of definitely been shorter and more precise. It is harder to tell what part of the centering is not working

Comment: Also, try to duplicate the layout in any html/css sandbox (fiddle or any other). This could lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
#menucontainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; /* ADD - make sure this container spans the entire screen */
    text-align: center; /* Align contents to the center */
}

#menu {
    /* remove position: fixed */
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0 auto;   /* Centers the block */
    text-align: left; /* Reset the text alignment */
    ... /* The rest stays the same */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
        #menucontainer{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: -420px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width:1218px;
        }

        #menu{
        position: relative;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        bottom:0px;
        height:200px;
        border:3px solid #000000;
        box-shadow:0px -5px 5px #888888;
        }

        li{
        float:left;
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-right:-10px;
        text-align:center;
        list-style:none;
        height:190px;
        width:300px;
        border-left:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }
       </style
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C2G4M/1/)

I've made some fundamential changes. 
Firstly, your `#menucontainer`. You don't need fixed position - we can use 'sticky footer' technique to make it allways be hitched to the bottom; as we know the width, `margin: 0 auto;` will help us center it horizontally.

```
#menucontainer{
    position:relative; 
    width: 1218px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;   
}
```

Secondy, I've added some fake content (`.fake-content` div) to help you get the idea how this all will look on site.

I've also added clearfix method for proper height rendering of an elements with floated children. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) (also easy to find anywhere else).

Sticky footer technique has been taken from [CSS Tricks site](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Any questions? Is that what you was looking for?